# PHP Mail attachment not opening or error file

Tags: php, html, email, sendmail, contact-form

it seems that this code is working but when I open the attachment on the mail, it can't be open or it is error. Everything is fine except for the attachment. Can someone please help. Thanks.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["send"]))  {  
  $subject = "Applicant";
  $name = $_POST['contact_name'];
  $position = $_POST['position'];

  $tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; 
  $fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type']; 
  $fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];

  # Open a file
  $file = fopen($tmpName, "r" );
  if( $file == false )
  {
     echo "Error in opening file";
     exit();
  }
  # Read the file into a variable
  $size = $_FILES['attachment']['size'];
  $content = fread( $file, $size);

  # encode the data for safe transit
  # and insert \r\n after every 76 chars.
  $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

  # Get a random 32 bit number using time() as seed.
  $num = md5( time() );

  # Define the main headers.
  $header = "From: Applicant\r\n";
  $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
  $header .= "boundary=$num\r\n";
  $header .= "--$num\r\n";

  # Define the position section
  $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit\r\n\n";
  $header .= "$name\r\n";
  $header .= "$position\r\n";
  $header .= "--$num\r\n";

  # Define the attachment section
  $header .= "Content-Type:  multipart/mixed; ";
  $header .= "name=\"$fileName\"\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Disposition:attachment; ";
  $header .= "filename=\"$fileName\"\r\n\n";
  $header .= "$encoded_content\r\n";
  $header .= "--$num--";

  $message = "Name: ".$name."\r\n"."Position: ".$position;

  # Send email now
  $retval = mail ('sample@gmail.com', $subject, $message, $header);
  if( $retval == true ){
   echo "<div style='border-style: solid; border: thick double #00386c; margin-bottom: 10px;'><h1 style='text-align: center; color: #00386c; padding: 10px;'>Your resume was sent! Thank you.</h1></div>";
    }else{
      echo "error";exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: are you using phpmailer to send mail???

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a phpmailer, but the code is upload in the server. @Lal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the attachment part in the email body.
Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST["send"])) {  
    $subject = "Applicant";
    $name = $_POST['contact_name'];
    $position = $_POST['position'];

    $tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; 
    $fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type']; 
    $fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];

    $message = "Name: ".$name."\r\n"."Position: ".$position;

    # Open a file
    # encode the data for safe transit
    # and insert \r\n after every 76 chars.
    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($tmpName)));

    # Get a random 32 bit number using time() as seed.
    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 

    # Define the main headers.
    $headers = "From: no-reply@example.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: no-reply@example.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\r\n";    
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    # Plain text section
    $body = "--PHP-mixed-" . $random_hash . "\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= $message;
    $body .= "\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= "\r\n--PHP-mixed-" . $random_hash . "\r\n\r\n";


    # Define the attachment section
    $body .= "--PHP-mixed-" . $random_hash . "\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: " . $fileType . "; name=\"" . $fileName . "\"\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $fileName . "\"\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= $encoded_content;
    $body .= "\r\n--PHP-mixed-" . $random_hash . "\r\n\r\n";



    # Send email now
    $retval = mail('sample@gmail.com', $subject, $body, $headers);

    if( $retval == true ) {
        echo "<div style='border-style: solid; border: thick double #00386c; margin-bottom: 10px;'><h1 style='text-align: center; color: #00386c; padding: 10px;'>Your resume was sent! Thank you.</h1></div>";
    } else{
        echo "error";exit;
    }
}
```